# Route keep asking for parameter even if not set to receive any

Tags: laravel, vue.js, laravel-routing, laravel-vue

I'm new to laravel and I'm having trouble with one of my web routes...

I grouped some routes with the auth middleware

```
Route::middleware(['auth:web'])->group(function ($router) {

    Route::get('/news', [NewsController::class, 'news'])->name('news');
    Route::get('/profile/{user_id}', [ProfileController::class, 'profile'])->name('profile');
    Route::get('/marketplace', [MarketplaceController::class, 'marketplace'])->name('marketplace');

});
```

Before this issue, I have set a `user_id` parameter for the `news` route and then removed it the next day, now the `news` route keeps returning error saying it needs `user_id`.

here's my controller:

```
    <?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

class NewsController extends Controller
{

    public function news() {

        return view('modules.news.news');

    }
}
```

and since im using laravel-vue mix, my `modules.news.news` view looks like this:

```
@section('content')
    <newsfeed inline-template>
        <div>
            ...
            ...
        </div>
    </newsfeed>
@endsection
```

I've checked the web route, the controller, the blade, and I really can't see anything that requiring the `news` route to receive a parameter.

can someone point out where I went wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your route file might be cached, try running php artisan route:clear and see if this fixes the issue.

Comment: Damn, took me almost an hour to resolve the issue and this is all I had to do. Sheez. Thanks man @Christian Holladay